# ordenamiento __cmp__ , ordenar segun dos parametros

Tags: python

Holaa

el codigo es el siguiente,

```
def es_numero(valor):
    return isinstance(valor, (int, float, long, complex) )

def es_cadena_no_vacia (valor):
    return isinstance (valor, (str))


class Hotel(object):

    def __init__ (self, nombre = '*', ubicacion = '*',
                 puntaje = 0, precio = float("inf")):


        if es_cadena_no_vacia (nombre):
            self.nombre = nombre
        else:
            raise TypeError ("El nombre debe ser una cadena no vacía")

        if es_cadena_no_vacia (ubicacion):
            self.ubicacion = ubicacion
        else:
            raise TypeError ("La ubicación debe ser una cadena no vacía")

        if es_numero(puntaje):
            self.puntaje = puntaje
        else:
            raise TypeError ("El puntaje debe ser un número")

        if es_numero(precio):
            if precio != 0:
                self.precio = precio
            else:
                self.precio = float("inf")
        else:
            raise TypeError("El precio debe ser un número")

    def __str__(self):
        """ Muestra el hotel según lo requerido. """
        return self.nombre + " de "+ self.ubicacion+ \
                " - Puntaje: "+ str(self.puntaje) + " - Precio: "+ \
                str(self.precio)+ " pesos."

    def ratio (self):
        """ Calcula la relación calidad-precio de un hotel de acuerdo a la fórmula que nos dio el cliente. """
        return ((self.puntaje**2)*10.)/self.precio

h1 = Hotel("Hotel Guadalajara", "Pinamar", 1, 35)

h2 = Hotel("Hostería París", "Aosario", 1, 35)

h3 = Hotel("Apart-Hotel Estocolmo", "Esquel", 3, 105)

h4 = Hotel("Posada El Cairo", "Salta", 2.5, 15)

lista = [ h1, h2, h3, h4 ]

lista.sort()

for Hotel in lista:

    print Hotel
```

el ejercicio que no estoy pudiendo resolver es el siguiente:

> Modificar el método **cmp** de Hotel para poder ordenar de menor a mayor las listas de hoteles según el criterio: primero por ubicación, en orden alfabético y dentro de cada ubicación por la relación calidad-precio.

o sea, si entiendo bien, si dos hoteles se llaman igual , ordenar segun calidad precio (de ratio).

Como lograria esto? Agradezco infinitamente cualquier respuesta orientativa al menos ya que carezco de algunos conocimientos, e intente algunas maneras, y no logro sacarlo.. puede que no este entendiendo bien/ o no este del todo bien expresado el enunciado del ejercicio? (de aca: https://librosweb.es/libro/algoritmos_python/capitulo_14/ejercicios_14.html)

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Hola, no está claro cuál es el problema que tienes. Te faltaría agregar qué estás haciendo para resolver tu tarea y el error o problema **específico** que enfrentas. Por cierto que en tu clase `Hotel` no hay ningún método `cmp`, así que es necesario que lo agregues a tu pregunta. Si no tienes idea de como empezar, mira esta pregunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052912/how-to-sort-dictionaries-of-objects-by-attribute-value-in-python

Comment: Lee sobre *dunder methods*, *magic methods* o *double underscore methods* en python. [Este](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) es un buen recurso para empezar. Lo que hace este método mágico es implementar el comportamiento de `<`, `>`, `==`,... Lo puedes hacer usando este método o los métodos `__lt__`, `__gt__`,...

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi solución:

```
# coding=utf-8


def es_numero(valor):
    return isinstance(valor, (int, float, long, complex))


def es_cadena_no_vacia(valor):
    return isinstance(valor, (str))


class Hotel(object):
    def __init__(self, nombre='*', ubicacion='*',
                 puntaje=0, precio=float("inf")):

        if es_cadena_no_vacia(nombre):
            self.nombre = nombre
        else:
            raise TypeError("El nombre debe ser una cadena no vacía")

        if es_cadena_no_vacia(ubicacion):
            self.ubicacion = ubicacion
        else:
            raise TypeError("La ubicación debe ser una cadena no vacía")

        if es_numero(puntaje):
            self.puntaje = puntaje
        else:
            raise TypeError("El puntaje debe ser un número")

        if es_numero(precio):
            if precio != 0:
                self.precio = precio
            else:
                self.precio = float("inf")
        else:
            raise TypeError("El precio debe ser un número")

    def __str__(self):
        """ Muestra el hotel según lo requerido. """
        return self.nombre + " de " + self.ubicacion + \
               " - Puntaje: " + str(self.puntaje) + " - Precio: " + \
               str(self.precio) + " pesos."

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if self.ubicacion == other.ubicacion:
            if self.ratio() > other.ratio():
                return 1
            elif self.ratio() < other.ratio():
                return -1
            else:
                return 0
        else:
            return self.ubicacion > other.ubicacion

    def ratio(self):
        """ Calcula la relación calidad-precio de un hotel de acuerdo a la fórmula que nos dio el cliente. """
        return ((self.puntaje ** 2) * 10.) / self.precio


h1 = Hotel("Hotel Guadalajara", "Pinamar", 1, 35)

h2 = Hotel("Hostería París", "Aosario", 1, 35)

h3 = Hotel("Apart-Hotel Estocolmo", "Esquel", 3, 105)

h4 = Hotel("Posada El Cairo", "Salta", 2.5, 15)

print h1 > h2
print h2 > h3
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a tu problema sería ordenar las columnas del siguiente modo, primero ordenas por calidad y posteriormente por el nombre del hotel.

Esta solución solo funciona si la ordenación conserva el orden de las instancias iniciales.